Why am I getting an error when I try to install Drupal?
I'm trying to expand my web dev skillset, so I installed Drupal 11.0.1 via cPanel/Softaculus to play with. However, the page refuses to load (HTTP ERROR 500) and this is the error shown in the error_log file:
[21-Aug-2024 15:22:59 America/Chicago] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home4/dluggon/public_html/commissions.neekko.art/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php on line 1636

screenshot of error_log
And this is the line causing the error in /core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php:
Request::setFactory([$request_factory, 'createRequest'](...));

screenshot of line 1636
As far as I can see, line 1636 isn't broken..?
I tried manually uninstalling Drupal by deleting all the files and the database, then tried reinstalling it manually using the ZIP downloaded from the official Drupal site. No improvement.
I tried commenting out the line, which didn't work. I also Ctrl+F'd the number of (), [], and {} to see if any were missing, but none are...
I am new to Drupal, though, so any insight into my issue is welcome!

What version of PHP are you running?

To second Chris: Drupal 11 requires PHP 8.3

I always forget about the PHP! It's running 7.4 and my host provider told me that they'll be rolling out 8.3 soon (but not soon enough!)...

Looks like installing an older version of Drupal works, so it's definitely the PHP version. I guess I'll play with 7.101 until my server gets the update. Thanks!

Turns out my server is still running PHP 7.4 and Drupal 11 requires 8.3. The site works now after I downgraded to Drupal 7.

"Turns out my server is still running PHP 7.4" - that's something you need to fix! PHP 7.4 is out of support, no official security updates are provided, and upgrading to PHP 8 has been recommended since years!
